# AdMob not working on my tablet

Tags: android, admob, tablet

I just installed Eclipse Helios, the latest Android SDK, and AdMob.
I'm trying to incorporate AdMob into my app, and it seems to be
working fine when I export the apk to my OG Droid (or run a 2.2 AVD),
but the ad banner isn't showing up at all on either my tablet (3.1) or
my tablet AVD. I'm trying to get the banner to appear on my start-up
screen.

My manifest includes this:

> ```
>    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="13"/>
> ```

I have this code in my startup screen java file:

> ```
>    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
>    adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);               
>    adRequest.addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID");
> ```

And this is in my startup screen xml:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="xxx" (omitted)
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

Any thoughts? (And to go "live," do I just delete the two
addTestDevice lines?)

Thx.

Comment: Looks like your manifest code didn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

1. See what logcat says

   ```
   adb logcat Ads:* *:S
   ```
2. Are you actually using the `AdRequest`?  It looks like you aren't.  You might want to nuke `ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"` and add

   ```
   AdView ad = (AdView) this.getViewById(R.id.adView);
   ad.requestAd(adRequest)`
   ```
3. `adRequest.addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID");` does absolutely nothing for you, unless you've sanitized out your device id for StackOverflow and are actually putting your device ID in here.  You can get your device ID from the logcat `Ads` logs.
4. When going live you can leave those in.  That's just a list of devices that should request test ads instead of live ones.  Leaving it in means your device and your emulator will only get test ads.  This way you can't accidentally release with test ads turned on for everybody.

Comment: Thx for the feedback. I get an error on your "ad.requestAd" statement that the method is undefined for type AdView.

Comment: Sorry, I was doing it from memory.  It's `ad.loadAd(adRequest)`

Comment: Well, that seems to work with my 2.2 AVDs, but the loadAd call throws an exception with my 3.1 emulator. The LogCat window isn't telling me anything when I step through that section of code. When I manually select that AVD at runtime (via the Android Device Chooser), the AVD does have a red X next to it. Is that a clue? The adb call you suggested seems to go away and never return.

Comment: The adb command line will watch the logs and only report things tagged with "Ads".  If you omit the `*:S` you'll see all of the logging in your phone/emulator.  It'll continue following the logs while you do stuff on the phone until you hit Ctrl+C.

What's the exception you get under 3.1?